# What is best way to show tooltip kind informative box with textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing some required validations on my input form. When user clicks on submit button I would like to show all required messages with respective input element in tooltip-like form, not at the top.

So what is the best way to do it in jQuery? Create one message container div and style it or there are plugins for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can use this jQuery Validation Engine

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

[image]

Here is an example 
http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

Answer (score 3):

Try jQuery Validation Engine plugin.

[jQuery VlidationEngine](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html)

Its very useful if your project is very large and have almost all the feature you needed.

Usage Example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
        });
```

and in HTML

```
<input type="text" class="validate[required]" id="txt_input" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a div with every input field and make it as display:none, then at validation show related field's div with required message.

And if you want to use plugin you can also use this one: [Default submitHandler](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)